# Is there any kind of relationship between Windows and Ubuntu installation?

Tags: boot, 13.10, grub2, usb, windows-8

I've just experienced incredibly weird behavior in Ubuntu. I've written lately some questions here regarding my shitty tablet not working correctly in Ubuntu 13.10 . I've left it that way having it without pressure sensitivity other stuff works and in Windows it just works, so I gave up on fixing that.

But just moments ago I accidentally damaged my Windows installation and it wouldn't boot. So to figure out how to fix it I've booted into Ubuntu to do some Google searching to get my Windows 8 installation fixed.

And as I tried to use my tablet instead of the mouse I've noticed it didn't move, but in xinput it reports that there is pressure sensitivity. So I thought to myself OK, maybe some accidental progress. I'll take a look into that later once I fix my Windows because I need it.

So had a couple restarts as I was trying to get to boot menu of Windows to do some recovery and from time to time I've gotten to Ubuntu to look for more clues and the tablet is always not moving my cursor but has pressure sensitivity..

I've recovered Windows from a restore point and checked that it works as it should. And then I'm going to Ubuntu to see what can I do to that tablet to maybe finally get it working somehow.

But guess what, I boot into Ubuntu and the tablet again works as it was previously, the cursor moves but no pressure sensitivity.

Now don't tell me this is some kind of accident. I've never seen any change to tablet behavior before Windows got broken and I've been at least 5-6 times to Ubuntu while Windows was not working (tablet behavior was different and always the same as it changed after Windows got broken) and once I fixed Windows from that moment, the tablet is again as it was before.

What is this supposed to mean? This is just too weird for me.

Comment: And it's getting even weirder.. So whenever i see something is acting weird in ubuntu i suspect nvidia drivers. This time it's not making much sense but still.. I've switched to noveau just for fun.. And now again the tablet is actually reporting pressure and what's better its even moving the cursor. So I'm really wondering what is happening between nvidia, ubuntu and windows installation? I feel a bit stupid asking this cause it's not making any sense.. But this behavior drives me mad.

Comment: It sounds like a hardware malfunction to me. There should be no other relationship between a linux and windows installation.

Comment: Just a suggestion in the meantime, but if you havn't already, you might want to try irc @ #ubuntu. Strange errors like this are extremely bothersome.

Comment: did your restore point include the partition with Ubuntu?

Comment: no, partition with ubuntu is "invisible" to windows.. and also the restore point was quite recent(definitely after ubuntu was installed) maybe just 3 or 4 days old and i created it manually. I don't think it's a hw malfunction. It's something with nvidia drivers i think.

Comment: This question seems to have been abandoned. There has not been further information or activity added to it for several months, and the questioner has not logged in since shortly after it was first posted.  I am flagging this to be closed. If you think this issue is still affecting you, you can flag a moderator to re-open it.